# Why does assembler move register value on stack and then back to register?

Tags: c++, assembly, disassembly, cpu-registers

When I disassemble some C++ code, sometimes I see assembler doing like this:

```
movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rdi
```

Isn't the second instruction useless? Why is it here?

Compiled with clang8 in debug mode with no specified optimization level. It only remains with `-O0` level, with `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3` it disappears.

Comment: Did you compile with optimization enabled?

Comment: This looks like a classic case of debug-mode code-gen, spilling a function arg and then reloading it for the first statement (that passes it to another function?  Normally compilers prefer EAX/RAX)  TL:DR of my answer on the linked duplicate: debug mode doesn't optimize across C++ statements so spill/reload is normal.

Comment: You didn't provide how you compiled the code.  `-O0`?  `-O3`?  (Or the MSVC++ equivalent.  Or whatever compiler you are using.)

Comment: Congratulations! You discovered that when not asked for careful code writing (optimization), compilers often write stereotypical, dumb code. (Doing otherwise takes time, and you asked not to care).

Comment: `-O0` is the default.